# AngularJS – how to write unit-test in Jasmine for enter events directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I have created **enter event directive** in **AngularJS**, so that i want to run test case for that directive. but i don't know how to write code for enter event.

```
describe('Unit Test: Enter Event', function() {
var elm, compile, scope;    

beforeEach(function() {
    module('att.sandbox.attEnterEvent');
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
});

/*scenarion 1*/
it("Enetr Key should call the method inside controller", function() {
    elm = angular.element('<input type="text" att-enter-event="enterEvent()">');
    elm = compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    scope.enterEvent = jasmine.createSpy();

     //**Here i want to add enter event test case** 

     expect().toHaveBeenCalled();
});
})
```

Comment: you mean enter key event yes ?

Comment: Yes.. I want to write test case for enter evet

Comment: I honestly do not understand what your actual query is

Comment: @Sprottenwels i want to write jasmine testcase for enter event.

Comment: you writing unit test or e2e test  ?

Comment: @ Narek Mamikonyan i want to write unit test case in jasmine

Comment: Please attach code for directive or even better – modify my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PtXFb/

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski, be careful when editing. Your title edit introduced two new typos in the title while you were supposed to be *fixing* it.

Comment: @kviiri Sorry for that ; /

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski, no problem, just be careful in the future ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski  please check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PtXFb/6/

Answer (score 3):

The most important things are:

- create event object
- modify directive
- write test

### [Create event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and trigger it on element

```
var ev = jQuery.Event("keydown", {
   keyCode: 13
});

el.trigger(ev); // as el is reference to compiled directive
```

```js
// ---IMPLEMETATION-----------------
angular.module('att.sandbox.attEnterEvent', [])
  .directive('hitEnterEvent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        hitEnterEvent: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
          if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.hitEnterEvent()
            });
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('hitEntereventCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showinputtext = false;
    $scope.enterEvent = function() {
      $scope.showinputtext = true;
    };
  });

// ---SPECS-------------------------
describe('Unit Test: Enter Event', function() {
  var el, scope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('att.sandbox.attEnterEvent');
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      el = $compile(angular.element('<input type="text" hit-enter-event="enterEvent()">'))(scope);
    });
  });

  it("Enter key should call the method inside controller", function() {
    scope.enterEvent = jasmine.createSpy('enterEvent');

    var enterKey = jQuery.Event("keydown", {
      keyCode: 13
    });

    el.trigger(enterKey);

    expect(scope.enterEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```